# Is it possible to fix Samsung XCover Pro lock/unlock?

Tags: samsung

The Samsung XCover Pro [advertises a large XCover and Top keys](https://youtu.be/0nkFctraI_o?t=88) that can be used to wake the device and launch apps with one press. Both have a setting called "Use while screen locked". With that setting enabled, and a PIN and/or fingerprint enabled to unlock the screen, I am unable to wake the device or launch apps from a locked screen as advertised. If the screen is off, pressing the buttons does nothing at all. If the screen is on, I have to enter my PIN first before any app will open, including apps that shouldn't need a PIN, like the camera. Even turning on the screen is a pain. There are two options: 1) Find the impossibly small, recessed wake button on the side, and press it, or 2) Enable "Lift to wake", which makes the phone think you are constantly scanning an invalid fingerprint, so the screen stays on, draining the battery and automatically disabling biometric unlocking.

I just want my Samsung XCover Pro to work as advertised. Has anyone found a solution to this?